# How to combine individual characters in one string in python

Tags: python

I have code like this:

```
def reverse(text):
    l=len(text)
    while ((l-1)!=0):
        print (str(text[l-1]))

        l=l-1
    print (str(text[0]))   

a=reverse("abc!de@fg")
```

The output is:

```
g
f
@
e
d
!
c
b
a
```

but I want to combine these individual characters and want out put like this:

```
gf@ed!cba
```

Comment: It is easier to simply `return text[::-1]` as your `reverse` function, unless this is a homework assignment or something

Comment: A function which is designed to `return` something typically wouldn't contain `print` statements. Return a string. Let the user of the function decide if they want to print the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def reverse(text):
    if len(text) <= 1:
        return text
    return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]
print (reverse('abc!de@fg'))
```

Comment: you need to concatenate each character.

Answer (score 3):

To print without the newline at the end of each line do:

```
print('text', end='')
```

To take a list of characters and make them one string, do:

```
''.join(list_of_characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to reverse a string:

```
In [1]: a = "abc!de@fg"

In [2]: print(a[::-1])
gf@ed!cba
```

The python `print` statement adds a newline by default. An easy way to print without newlines is

```
sys.stdout.write('some text')
# or
print('some text', end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to concatenate them and then print the string result.

This is because the function `print` automatically does a break line.

A fix would be:

```
def reverse(text):
       l = len(text)
       aux = ''

       while l-1 != 0:
           aux += str(text[l-1])
           l = l - 1

       print (aux)   
       a = reverse("abc!de@fg")`
```

P.S: Try to avoid redundant parenthesis =)

Comment: additional to @Wrong answer, If there is no return , just call it out and no assignment is needed

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to put the print value in variable and print that at the end. Like this.

```
def reverse(text):
    l=len(text)
    output = ""
    while ((l-1)!=0):
        output += (str(text[l-1]))

        l=l-1
    output +=(str(text[0]))

    print output
a=reverse("abc!de@fg")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the simplest way to reverse a [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types) is with a slice:

```
>>> string="abc!de@fg"
>>> print(string[::-1])
gf@ed!cba
```

Slicing will give you a copy of the sequence in reverse order.

In general, you want a function to do one thing. Returning a value and printing some output are separate concerns, so they should not be conflated in the same function. If you have a function that returns a reversed string, you can simply print the function:

```
print(reverse("abc"))
```

Then, you can see that your actual algorithm is fine, if not entirely Pythonic:

```
def reverse(text):
    l=len(text)
    output = ""
    while ((l-1)!=0):
        output += (str(text[l-1]))
        l=l-1
    output +=(str(text[0]))
    return output
```

You can clearly see now that it's the print function in your way.